# SceneKit Error: C3DSkinnerUpdateJointsAndBoundingBox skinner has no mesh

Tags: swift, scenekit, xcode9.3

When I load the .scn file downloading for my server and store locally in the user domain directory and when I use those file in Scene Kit, 
I am getting this error where I was not able to apply animation dynamically. Since the bone and skinner is not joint. SCN File contains the skin geometry mesh nodes and bone nodes(rig).

```
        do {
            let options = [ SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption.convertToYUp : true ]
            let scene = try SCNScene(url: fileURL , options: options)
            for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
                baseNode.addChildNode(childNode)
            }
        }catch let error as NSError {
           NSLog("Unable to load file \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
```

code loads and I was able to see the model but it does load skinner. and getting the error as ***"[SceneKit] Error: C3DSkinnerUpdateJointsAndBoundingBox skinner has no mesh"***.

Note: If I use the all character and animations dae file in the assets folder and use it in the code it works great.(I converted the dae to scn file using xcode)

Answer (score 1):

This is a system level logging. You can disable this by adding the following flag in your Target's Environment Setting:
OS_ACTIVITY_MODE - disable

Step1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason it is not with the scn file or rig, It is with animation.
when this below line is added in the animation it worked well.
animation.usesSceneTimeBase = false

Comment: The above line worked for me. Also, note we can use compressed DAE format.

Comment: Ok, for me it wasn't working.. I didn't made changes to DAE files though.. I got one approach which I added as answer.